# Unable to click on button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

For this line,

```
driver.findElement(By.name("importbutton")).click();
```

It is throwing exception:

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 20.08 seconds.
```

The following is the html code for above,

```
<div class="text-center msg">
<button class="btn-w center-block btn btn-default reveal" ng-click="gplus_login()" type="button" name="importbutton">Import Gmail Contacts</button>
</div>
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: You need to have some kind of wait. Refer my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Include an implicit or explicit (favorably, the later), before this click statement.

This is an example of how you use **Explicit wait** :

```
WebdriverWait wait1= new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
WebElement ele= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityof(elementtobechecked);
```

then include your click statement

```
driver. findElement(By.name("importbutton")).click();
```

If you want to use **implicit wait** (which I wouldn't recommend), then you can use :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You can use the Selenium documentation to refer more.

Here is a good [example](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/selenium-webdriver-waits-selenium-tutorial-15/).

Answer (score -1):

```
 //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    if(driver.findElement(By.name("importbutton")).isDisplayed())
    system.out.Println("test passed");
    driver.findElement(By.name("importbutton")).click();
    Else
    system.out.Println("test Fail")
```

Try this you might get Successs

Comment: This contains two anti-patterns. 1. ImplicitWait, better is to use an Explicit wait, because implicitwait adds a wait for each Selenium findElement and more, which slows down your tests. 2. Thread.sleep, you should never need this if you use Explicit waits.

Comment: i said use anyone java sleep method  or implicit wait

Comment: This answer can not be Downvote. Because last possible solution is Thread.sleep(milisecond); May be this is right answer.

Comment: Sleep is never the answer, it will just create the risk of flickering tests and wasted time when figuring out why the test is failing. I cannot come up with a situation where its not possible to use an explicit wait, where you wait for an element to be visible, in a certain state or not visible at all. Colleague's using sleeps and implicit waits have wasted a lot of my time already, I suggest you never use either of them, just try to solve the problem as if they do not exist. This is similar to using GOTO in your code, it might have it uses, but regularly this is a very bad practise.

Comment: @Niels van Reijmersdal   hi i know you might be right, i tried many in built  wait commands like implicit,explicit,fluent wait commands are didnt work for me when iam using appium to automate an ios app. i think you may be beginner in case of app automation....

Comment: This question was not about app automation, but you are right I have not yet automated mobile apps. Even then sleeps sound like a hackish patch, but if it works for you please keep using it :) I just think its bad general advice, but sometimes after trying other options there might not be a better solution for the time being. I might opt getting the developers to changes the application behavior so that the sleep is not needed instead, this could be better IDs, better timing of transitions, adding hidden data to check the current application state, making it better testable.